# How to make this if statement in shell

Tags: shell, if-statement

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this if statement. I want to do this:

> IF (the function has only 1 argument
>   AND $1 is a directory (in the current
>   folder)) OR IF (the function has 2
>   arguments AND $1 is NOT a directory ) THEN
>
> ```
> ....
> ```
>
> END

Sorry if it's not very clear,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pretty much said what is needed in the question:

```
if [ $# = 1 -a -d "$1" ] || [ $# = 2 -a ! -d "$1" ]
then
    ...
fi
```

You can use other operators too - that will work in Bourne shell, let alone Korn or other POSIX shells (assuming that $# works correctly in a function - which it does in Bash).

```
fun()
{
    if [ $# = 1 -a -d "$1" ] || [ $# = 2 -a ! -d "$1" ]
    then echo "Pass ($1, $#)"
    else echo "Fail ($1, $#)"
    fi
}

fun $HOME
fun $HOME abc
fun $HOME/xyz abc
fun /dev/null
```

Comment: Note that you can use the '-o' operator in the test ('[') built-in; long-standing (but not necessarily still relevant) advice is to not try messing with both '-a' and '-o' (or, even, with either '-a' or '-o').  Doing things as shown is reliable and avoids the need to escape brackets (parentheses), etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
if [[ $# == 1 && -d "$1" ]]; then
  echo "one param, first is a dir"
elif [[ $# == 2 && ! -d "$1" ]]; then
  echo "two params, first is not a dir"
else
  echo "unexpected"
fi
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants "or" rather than `elif`.

Comment: It's likely to want to do something (slighly) different in each case, which this shows in the example.